# interbase and BDE on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, interbase, bde

OK I know this has been deprecated, and bde is older than Moses, but we have some legacy applications that have not been migrated still using bde.

Has anyone been successfull in installing bde WITH the interbase sql links fully configured for windows 7 (32 and 64 bit)?

I have found a many different posts and executables, but nothing conclusive.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

finally found a solution that works nicely. Though i should share it

download: **[Borland Database Engine (including SQL Links)](http://www.all2ezy.com/html/developer_downloads.htm)**

works nicely. I have tested it our on widows 7 32 and 64 bit, both work beautifully

Comment: I know this is frowned upon, but I'm going to say thank you regardless.

Comment: Pleasure. I haven't worked in interbase for yonks but glad to hear that this is still relevant. And a fellow south African.  Awesome

Comment: As someone just coming across this now. I've installed the files, but what program do I select to open the .db files?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is way old but BDE 5.2.0.2 works on Windows 7 without issues.
Just point to the DB with LocalHost:DBPATH