# How to open the .db paradox file

Tags: vb.net, paradox

i want to view the test.db file, i search for it's editor but didn't get any one
So please help to see the it in editor as like sql server.

i found some sqlite editor but it's not an sqlite file on most forum it say that it is an paradox .db file.

So how do i open it

Thanks

Comment: Please try this http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Comment: Hi roshan lal, i tried this software , it is not working and it is not a sqlite database. when i imported the file to sqlite database browser it shows its not a SQLite 3 database.Do you know anything else??

Comment: Microsoft"s Access, SQLite and Corel Paradox I found these three application.

Answer (score 5):

To access Paradox tables in .NET you can use ODBC. Here's a small example (in C#):

```
private static void RunMinimumParadoxTest()
{
    const string ConnectionStringFormat =
        "Driver={{Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )}};Uid={0};UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;" +
        "ParadoxUserName={0};ParadoxNetStyle=4.x;ParadoxNetPath={1};PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;" +
        "MaxBufferSize=65535;DriverID=538;Fil=Paradox 7.X;DefaultDir={2};Dbq={2};CollatingSequence={3}";

    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.Odbc");
    using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        string userName = "Tor";
        string paradoxNetPath = @"C:\BdeNet";
        string databasePath = @"C:\LangloMainSrv\LData\Ordre\LordWin\Database2011";
        string collatingSequence = "Norwegian-Danish";
        connection.ConnectionString = 
            String.Format(ConnectionStringFormat, userName, paradoxNetPath, databasePath, collatingSequence);
        connection.Open();
        using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "select Count(*) from [OrdreDet] where [Ordrenr] = 81699002";
            object itemCount = command.ExecuteScalar();
            Console.WriteLine("Order items: {0}", itemCount);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Also see the following link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710922(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: For people _still_ supporting Paradox databases, the paradoxNetPath above refers to the directory of the Borland Database Engine which I found I had to install before anything (this code, Excel and my EDL tool) could connect via ODBC. Check out this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670104/interbase-and-bde-on-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

A Paradox db file contains just one flat table. The actual structure of the DB file changed over time and different versions. But you can usually open the DB file with MS Excel - of course that changed over different versions too.

As noted above, other database applications, also including Paradox for Dos and Paradox for Windows, will open the file and other features as well. The key, for example is in the PX file with the same table name.

All of this assumes the table is not password protected, which an application database could be - or that you know the password. Beware if you get an error to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can open and view Paradox database files using Database Desktop that is shipped with Borland C++Builder. A free alternative is [BB's Database Desktop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bbdbd/). The software may require administrator privileges to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnumeric spreadsheet, paradox-db-reader or BB database desktop to read db paradox file.
BB database dekstop able to read XG0 file too.

Answer (score 0):

BB's Database Desktop now called JEDI Database Desktop, but project is closed and it couldn't edit my table. I have had to use some hack: open *.db file in MS Excel 2007, edit it, export to *.csv, close file then Open *.db file in Paradox Data Editor 3.2.0, clear all table data and import previosly saved csv-file. And it works (don't know why but this app can't insert row in my file itself)!