# Paradox database file

Tags: file-format, paradox, data-extraction, gnumeric

I found paradox database files with different extension.

There are db file, `mb` file, `dat` file, `px` file, `XG0` file, `XG1` file, `XG2` file, `XG3` file, `XG4` file, `YG0` file, `YG1` file, `YG2` file, `YG3` file and `YG4` file.

I already found way to open db file and px file using gnumeric spreadsheet. I found some of needed data from db file. But, rest of data not in db file. So, i have to open rest of files. I cant find software that can read those files.

Comment: Able to read the content of YGO, YG1, YG2, YG3 , YG4 and PX file using Direct Paradox table shareware software. But, I still find way to read the rest of the file.  anyone cn help me? thank you

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Borland has never documented the Paradox file format, so there's no definitive information available.

Anyway:

- the actual data are in the `.db` files (tables) and `.mb` files (memo/blob info, at least Paradox level 4)
- `.px` files contain primary index information. `.xg?` / `.yg?` are for secondary index(es). Those are auxiliary files which Paradox uses to store the indexes
- the `.dat` file is more than likely the program's configuration data (try to open it with a text editor, it should contain ASCII text)
- `.val` files are for formatting / constraint handling
- `.sc` files are script, `.qbe` queries

So your data are in `.db`/`.mb` files. If something is missing you could have corrupted files. Try Paradox file repair (see link below) with a copy of your data.

Further details:

- [Paradox Specifications](http://www.randybeck.com/paradoxformat.shtml)
- [Paradox file repair](http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/172.htm)
- [pxlib](http://pxlib.sourceforge.net/). Library to read and write Paradox databases
- [How to open the .db paradox file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15948333/3235496)
- [BB's Database Desktop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bbdbd/).  Replaces and extends Borland Database Desktop, which is not free. The goal of this project is to implement the functions of the original Database Desktop and add some useful features.

Comment: Thank you manlio. How to install knoda-0.8.3.tar.bz2? Is the knoda run on ubuntu? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don‘t know knoda. From the project homepage it seems you have to compile the sources. Anyway try with a new question on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

As was stated, the DB and MB files were the only files that contained data.
PX and the XG/YG pairs were simply indexes with no new data.
Paradox tables (DB and MB) could be password encrypted, which may be why you could not read the data, if you do not have the password.